# Why would "half orange" be a term of endearment?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

In [this comic](http://www.gocomics.com/espanol/luannspanish/2015/03/22), Luanne lists terms of endearment, "media naranja" being one. This is a new one on me, and I can't figure out why "half orange" would be much more endearing than "half wit."

Is it an indication that you are not whole without the other person, that with them you become a complete person, or what?

Comment: That is a very interesting topic. _Media naranja_ is something many, many people use and it is quite a surprising concept for the Spanish learners : )

Comment: Strange... I always assumed it translated to *orange stocking* rather than *half orange*.

Comment: @Paul: Even if so, my question would be: Why would "orange stocking" be an expression of endearment, any more than "purple glove" would be? Besides, wouldn't "orange stocking" be something like "calcetinas naranjas"?